# modernCV: Increase the left size along with heading

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, moderncv

I want to increase the heading space on the  left side of modern-CV so that I can write "Software Version Control" in one line. On the right side, there is a lot of white space so that's why I want to push the black headings along with the blue box to expand it.

**Mine:**

[image]

**Sample:**

[image]

Comment: I solved it by something like `\mbox{\makebox[50pt]{\hfill some long text}\hspace{-20pt}}`. This or similar allows you to write into the margin.

Comment: No, It is wrong. I want to wide the blue box in term width. In above code, It did not work out.

Comment: It's not wrong, it's an alternative solution, which you don't like. It's a difference. I know exactly, that it doesn't change the blue line. Try `\show\section` or something like this then check the log. There you should see the definition of section and what you have to change in there.

Comment: You should also add a MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the width of box

```
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
```